# are datasets confined to power bi service

Tags: powerbi

I tried to find information about datasets in power BI, and it looks like the concept of datasets comes in Power BI Service environment only; to confirm my understanding, I tried to find information on google : **"datasets in power BI desktop"** which again gave me datasets in power BI service.

I am relatively a new learner of Power BI, and hence my question would be a basic one.

Would anyone please comment on my understanding; Thank you for giving your valuable time.

Comment: A .pbix file contains the dataset for a Power BI report but I'm not sure what you mean specifically. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a report in PBI Desktop, you are creating a data model. This data model will hold everything for that report.

When you deploy the report to the service, it splits out that file into its two elements, a dataset as seen in the dataset tab that hold the information (based on the data model), and reports, that hold the visuals.

Once in the service, you can share that dataset, build new reports from it in the service, or link PBI Desktop to the dataset in the service. This allows you to create multiple variations of reports from the same dataset, that reduces data duplication in the service, saves space, and when you have to update the data model or reports makes it a bit easier. More info on sharing datasets across the organisation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-datasets-across-workspaces).

Datasets are confined to the service and there are two main ways of getting the data, connecting PBI desktop to the dataset, or using [Analyze in Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-analyze-in-excel). Best practice is that you use PBI as a data analysis and consumption layer, not as a data source in itself, for example, extracting the data from the data set to another data source for further transformation.

Comment: Jon, thanks for your giving your valuable time; and your explanation definitely helped me.

Comment: Besides the informaiton you shared me, I am trying find a legitimate source from Microsoft publication to find information about .PBIX file, what includes within the file and etc; but, unfortunately, I didn't find any direct source of information from Microsoft. May be, I have to do more search on it. Would you please help me on this? Thank you!

Comment: The PBIX file is a zip file. If you change the file extension to .zip, you can see inside it. It will hold the data in a csv style format, and JSON items for the visuals and other settings. More info here https://www.fourmoo.com/2017/05/02/what-makes-up-a-power-bi-desktop-pbix-file/

Answer (score 0):

Once you create power bi dashboard from power bi desktop app you need to publish to the tenant. That power bi .pbix file deployed as report and dataset file.

Report : Your implementations deployed as report.
Dataset : Dataset related to the published dashboard.

Once you installed gateway you can sync dataset with your datasource